# MacOS file with strange behavoir

Tags: mac, finder

realm (https://realm.io a database system) created a file on my macOS system, called "sample.realm.note". This file has some weird properties:

- It does not show up in Finder though it should show up (its name does not start with a dot and it should show according to its attributes)
- cp and cat commands do not exit nor show anything, mv does work (tested with root, not a permission problem)
- Even it does not display in Finder, it's possible to overwrite it by saving something with the same filename. The new file has the same strange properties
- It crashes some software that's scanning the file (for example Babel-node)

ls shows the following:

```
prw-------   1 <user>  staff       0 Feb 26 17:51 sample.realm.note
```

GetFileInfo:

```
file: "/Users/<user>/Desktop/sample.realm.note"
type: "\0\0\0\0"
creator: "\0\0\0\0"
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 02/26/2018 17:42:54
modified: 02/26/2018 17:51:40
```

Is this an error by realm, by macOS or even by myself?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Comment: Thank you @ignacio-vazquez-abrams. Didn't know about that!